# Open port with TinyWall

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

[Tinywall](https://tinywall.pados.hu/) allows me to whitelist programs on all ports or on certain ports, but it doesn't seem to allow opening certain ports for all programs.

I tried to add the rules manually, but that doesn't work because tinywall also prevents modifications done by anything other than itself. eg: when I add the rule, and then refresh or close the windows firewall interface and reopen it, the rule is gone.

The reason I'm trying to get this done is because I have a couple games, warframe being one of them, that will not patch unless I disable Windows Firewall. It constantly shows a connection error when windows firewall is enabled. I've already whitelisted the launcher as well as both x86 and x64 executables.

I know its the firewall and not antivirus or IP blocklists because I've disabled each of them one by one, and disabling windows firewall will allow the launcher to patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same issue with warframe and my solution is as follows.

Use the Group Policy Editor to add rules to BOTH inbound and outbound for the 3 programs - Warframe x86, Warframe x64 and the Launcher.

Basically add "program" based rules and simply allow connection for those apps.

Doing this via the Group Policy Editor seems to bypass the overriding influence of TinyWall and the rules do not vanish - at least they didn't for me.

Screenshot: [image: http://www.shareimages.com/image.php?84268-pJScl5qik5.sl5yVlqg-lgpe.png]

Comment: Confirmed working with windows 10

Comment: I wanted to **block** a specific port for every program and this workaround works too for that.